# Как сделать табличку на telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать такую табличку чтобы выводилась при нажатии на inline кнопку?
[image: табличка]

Comment: Можете привести ссылку на бота где это реализовано?

Comment: Что-то я таблицы именно как штуки с ячейками воспринимаю, а не как всплывающие диалоговые окна :D

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно создать такой же виджет то вот код (нужно будет нажать ок, для того чтоб пропал виджет)

```
  bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, show_alert=True, text="Здесь напиши текст который будет в этом виджете")
```

[image: Выглядит вот так]
Но а если нужно чтоб этот виджет появился на мгновение и потом пропал (не нужно нажимать ок)

```
  bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, show_alert=False, text="Здесь напиши текст который будет в этом виджете")
```

[image: Выглядит вот так]

А если нужен пример то вот

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def _test_(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Название кнопки", callback_data="test")
    keyboard.add(callback_button)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здесь напиши текст соообщения", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "test":
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, show_alert=True, text="Здесь тест")
```

[image: Так выглядит сообщение]
[image: Так выглядит виджет]